# depth of a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, treenode

so I need to write a function in c++ that returns the depth of the tree. Im a bit confussed as to what this entails. It is the depth of each individual node or is it the depth of the entire tree for example the tree has 4 levels. any help would be appreciated

Comment: That usually refers to the depth of the entire tree. But be careful, trees may not be uniform in depth, i.e. your tree may have some leaves at depth 3 and some at depth 4, in that case the depth of the tree would be 4.

Comment: You may need to review the definition of "depth of tree"?

Comment: A good idea is to update the depth and node counts as new nodes are added or moved.

Answer (score 0):

The depth of a tree is the level of the deepest node. That looks like a good definition. Having said that, here's an implementation in a class in C++ where root is an attribute of the class. Basically, you get the depth of the left sub-tree and the depth of the right sub-tree, and choose whichever is the biggest of those two.

```
#define max(a,b)  ((a)>=(b) ? (a) : (b))



int height2(Node *t) {
  if(!t) 
    return 0;
  int height_left  = height2(t->L);
  int height_right = height2(t->R);
  return 1 + max(height_left,height_right);
};


int height() {
  return height2(root);
};
```

Comment: Sorry about that? Didn't know

Comment: Besides such usage of macro here reduces code efficiency considerably.

Comment: As Valeri said, better to store returns of depths in variables and then run macros on them. You are calculating the depth twice for each node.

Comment: And *please* don't begin method names (or variable names for that matter) with an underscore. Such names are reserved.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node {
public:
    //...
    unsigned int depth() {
        return 1 + max(depth(left),
                       depth(right));
    }
private:
    unsigned int depth(Node* node) {
        return node ? node->depth() : 0;
    }
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
```